# Namespace refactoring in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am refactoring namespaces of small part of a large project. So I have refactored following 2 files which had `Oldname` as the namespace to `x::y::z`.

file1.hpp

```
namespace x::y::z
{

Class abc
{
public:
       void funcA(type1 arg1, type2 arg2)   
}
```

file1.cpp

```
#include "file1.hpp"

namespace x::y::z
{
void abc::funcA(type1 arg1, type2 arg2)
{
--------
}
}
```

Now I am resolving this file 2 which has dependencies with the above file. I do not want to change the namespace of this file, but just modify the functions that depend on the above files.

file2.cpp

```
#include "file1.hpp"

namespace Oldname
{
 void abc::funcA(type1 arg1, type2 arg2)
{
      mock("txt")
         .actualCall("abc.funcA")
         .withParameter("arg1", arg1)
         .withParameter("arg2", arg2)

}
}
```

I tried to make it as follows,

```
namespace Oldname
{
   void x::y::z::abc::funcA(type1 arg1, type2 arg2)
{
      mock("txt")
          .actualcall("abc.funcA")
          .withParameter("arg1",arg1)
          .withParameter("arg2",arg2)
}
}
```

However, I get the following error,

```
error: cannot define or redeclare 'funcA' here because namespace 'Oldname' does not enclose namespace 'abc'
```

Can someone help how to resolve this error?

Comment: Even before changing the namespace, wouldn't this have violated the ODR?

Comment: Add `::` before `x`, so it'll read `::x::y::z::abc::funcA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Namespaces) (emphasis added):

> Out-of-namespace definitions and redeclarations are only allowed after the point of declaration, only at namespace scope, and **only in namespaces that enclose the original namespace** (including the global namespace) and they must use qualified-id syntax

Given this rule, the definition of `::x::y::z::abc::funcA` is allowed

- in the definition of the class (`::x::y::z::abc`),
- in namespace `::x::y::z`,
- in namespace `::x::y`,
- in namespace `::x`, or
- in the global namespace.

It is not allowed in any other namespaces. In particular, it is not allowed in the namespace `Oldname`. To resolve this error (without introducing `namespace x` to `file2.cpp`), take your definition out of `Oldname` and put it in the global namespace. Or maybe re-think how your namespaces are set up.